# mysql inserting data in more than one table:

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I created database which contains many tables has relation between each others,

I made a form which add books to a table named `book`. In this table there's a column named `author_author_id` which contains the id from table `author` and `user_user_id` the same story. The other table called `genre` has a many-to-many relation to `book`.

I added user and author and genre ids directly to database, but what exactly is the query I  have to use to insert in book table all the data with a single statement!

I'm new in php coding so excuse my stupid and shallow questions and my way describing the problem.

Comment: Insert the book record first, which allows you to get the last used ids for the book to use in the other records you need to insert.... but make sure the whole set of inserts is wrapped in a transaction

Comment: okay thank u man, but my problem still in the query too!

Answer (score 1):

The function [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) returns the ID of the last inserted row.

```
<?php

$link = // Connect to the database using the mysqli driver

// Create author (if not exists already)
mysqli_query($link, 'INSERT INTO authors (name, ...) VALUES ("author name", ...)');
$author_id = mysqli_insert_id($link, $link);

// Escape ID
$author_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $author_id);

// Create the book
mysqli_query($link, 'INSERT INTO books (name, author_id ...) VALUES ("book name", ' . $author_id . ' ...)');
$book_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

// Escape ID
$book_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $book_id);

// Add the genres
mysqli_query($link, 'INSERT INTO genres (book_id, genre_id) VALUES (' . $book_id . ', ...)');
```

This code uses the procedural `mysqli_*` functions. This isn't the cleanest way to proceed, and the code above should **only be seens as indications on how to proceed**. For the sake of clean code (well, in PHP standards), look into PDO for a cleaner database access model.

- [A tutorial on PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) (found on Google, haven't fully checked it out)
- [PHP manual page on PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)
- [The “Choosing and API” guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) from the PHP docs

Comment: Yeah, sorry. My PHP days are far behind me. I was tryin to give a "beginner solution" without running into these notions. I fought the same battle long ago, so i'll edit right away ;–)